# Delete Analysis Services database using T-SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, t-sql, ssas

Is it possible to modify (delete) SSAS databases using T-SQL?

Background:

We have a Web Application that builds and deploys a SQL Analysis Services database and cube with a structure based on a dynamic query generated by user selections. This works fine, but when these conditions are removed we need to delete the database as well. I can modify the C# dll we've built to do a delete on certain conditions, but we already have a stored procedure that's triggered by the DLL to delete other db content and I'd prefer to add to this stored proc to delete the Analysis Services database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a linked server in SQL to connect to SSAS:
http://sqlblog.com/blogs/stacia_misner/archive/2010/11/30/31193.aspx

Then use the EXECUTE AT syntax mentioned here to execute your Delete XMLA command:
http://www.sqlsoldier.com/wp/sqlserver/usingdynamicvaluesinxmla

Comment: Although I ended up making the changes in the DLL, this solution would've allowed me to run the "updates" within SQL.

Answer (score 2):

To the best of my knowledge, No. It is not possible to modify or delete an SSAS database using TSQL. It might be possible using XMLA. But, personally, I'd use PowerShell for this:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::Load("Microsoft.AnalysisServices, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91, processorArchitecture=MSIL");

$amo = New-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server;
$amo.Connect("data source=localhost");

$amo.Databases["yourASdb"].Drop();
```